# Fixed, full height sidebar scrolling issue on iOS

Tags: ios, css, ipad, scroll, fixed

I'm having a problem with a `position: fixed` sidebar which has full-height when over-scrolling the body and then suddenly scroll back top.

Here is a video of the process i made on the ipad simulator (the same issue occurs when testing on the actual device).
http://www.screencast.com/t/SKEwFbx2tYvE (sorry for the big jing video size)

I also put a demo and a jsfiddle so you can test it yourself and play with it:
http://epicco.me/sandbox/scrolling_demo/
http://jsfiddle.net/qnB7z/

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no easy fix for this. The white part you are seeing is the webview background. It happens when you catch the view on bounce. You can set an absurd height on that element and still have the same issue.

Comment: @KerimIncedayi thanks, actually setting the sidebar height to 200% worked out well and it didn't broke anything as it was fixed anyway.

Comment: @KerimIncedayi do you know if there is a more up to date fix to this problem?